Avoiding @Sendable for Callbacks in Timer-Based Swift 6 API Manager
I'm upgrading my API manager to Swift 6, but I’m running into issues with @Sendable requirements for callbacks due to Timer usage.
In my API manager, I have methods that take completion callbacks (like onSuccess, onFailure, etc.) which are then executed within a Timer. These callbacks are triggered based on network connectivity checks, retries, and timeouts within the Timer. However, Swift 6 requires the Timer’s closure to be @Sendable, and since my callbacks capture various non-sendable types, adding @Sendable isn’t an option for me.
Is there a way to structure this so that I can still use the Timer and callbacks without needing to mark them as @Sendable? Alternatively, are there any patterns that allow keeping callbacks without modifying the whole API manager to avoid @Sendable?
Here's a simplified version of the problematic code:
func performRequest<T: Decodable>(
    request: T,
    onSuccess: @escaping (T) -> Void,
    onFailure: @escaping (Error) -> Void,
    onOffline: (() -> Void)? = nil
) {
    // Network check and timer setup
    Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true) { timer in
        // Callbacks are invoked here
        if someCondition {
            onSuccess(someResult)
        } else {
            onFailure(someError)
        }
    }
}

What’s the best approach here to avoid @Sendable requirements without rearchitecting the entire API manager?
Any help or best practices for handling this in Swift 6 would be greatly appreciated!

I'd redesign this so that performRequest doesn't take callbacks. Instead it can return an AsyncSequence<RequestState> where RequestState is an enum that encodes the 3 different states (success, failure, offline). Instead of timer, you can wait using Task.sleep(for: .seconds(1)). Is that an option for you?

I'm currently aiming to avoid modifications to the broader codebase, which relies on the existing callback structure. Adjusting performRequest to use AsyncSequence would likely require changes across multiple parts of the code that are built around the callback pattern.
Is there a way to implement the core functionality of this approach—like using Task.sleep—without needing to replace callbacks entirely?

I would redesign it anyway, because - honestly - the design of the API calls for troubles.

@CouchDeveloper what do you think, should I spend some time and make them Sendable (I assume it is less effort than the mentioned redesign) ?

Making them sendable isn’t always an option. I think there is too little information regarding how you are using performRequest for us to determine which is easier.

An API could be represented with this function (Input) async throws(APIError) -> Output, where Input and Output are value types and sendable. Internally, the function does encode the input, creates parameters for a HTTP request, calls a function which executes the request and also receives a network configuration (a sendable value type, containing base URLs, additional headers, authorisation provider etc.), and returns a HTTP response which need to be decoded to the Output, respectively an APIError needs to be composed. I see no issue regarding Sendable.

In contrast, your API seems to receive a T which is some sort of InputAndOuptut. This doesn't work well.

Here is my workaround for your solution:
func performRequest<T: Decodable>(
    request: T,
    onSuccess: @escaping (T) -> Void,
    onFailure: @escaping (Error) -> Void,
    onOffline: (() -> Void)? = nil
) {
    // Network check and timer setup
    var comple = Completion<T>()
    comple.onFailure = onFailure
    comple.onSuccess = onSuccess
    Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true) { [comple] timer in
        // Callbacks are invoked here
        if true {
            comple.onSuccess?()
        } else {
            comple.onFailure?(NSError(domain: "", code: 0))
        }
    }
}

struct Completion<T: Decodable>: @unchecked Sendable {
    var onFailure: ((Error) -> Void)?
    var onSuccess: ((T) -> Void)?
}


Not sure if this is a valid workaround. It silences the error, but does not fix potential data races and race conditions. Well, the original code has this too, because "making this objects  sendable is not an option", which hints to the fact, it's already bugged. But in this case, I just would not use Swift 6, and hope for the best. ;)

Yeah not using Swift 6 is the best option for him :)

You can retire the Timer.scheduledTimer and instead just loop with Task.sleep:
@MainActor
class ApiManager {
    private var task: Task<Void, any Error>?

    func performRequest<T: Decodable>(
        request: T,
        onSuccess: @escaping (T) -> Void,
        onFailure: @escaping (any Error) -> Void,
        onOffline: (() -> Void)? = nil
    ) {
        // cancel previous, if any
        task?.cancel()

        task = Task {
            …

            while !Task.isCancelled {
                try await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(1))

                if someCondition {
                    onSuccess(someResult)
                } else {
                    onFailure(someError)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

That requires that performRequest is actor-isolated. I just isolated the whole type, but if you want to isolate performRequest (and task) individually, you can do that, too.

Alternatively, you can use AsyncTimerSequence from Apple’s swift-async-algorithms package:
@MainActor
class ApiManager {
    private var task: Task<Void, any Error>?

    func performRequest<T: Decodable>(
        request: T,
        onSuccess: @escaping (T) -> Void,
        onFailure: @escaping (any Error) -> Void,
        onOffline: (() -> Void)? = nil
    ) {
        // cancel previous, if any
        task?.cancel()

        task = Task {
            …

            for await _ in AsyncTimerSequence(interval: .seconds(1), clock: .continuous) {
                if someCondition {
                    onSuccess(someResult)
                } else {
                    onFailure(someError)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


Personally, I would generally stay within structured concurrency:
@MainActor
class ApiManager {
    func performRequest<T: Decodable>(
        request: T,
        onSuccess: @escaping (T) -> Void,
        onFailure: @escaping (any Error) -> Void,
        onOffline: (() -> Void)? = nil
    ) async {
        …

        for await _ in AsyncTimerSequence(interval: .seconds(1), clock: .continuous) {
            if someCondition {
                onSuccess(someResult)
            } else {
                onFailure(someError)
            }
        }
    }
}

But that would likely require a more general refactoring of the call points, which I gather you are trying to minimize.

I would not advise it, but you could also use a GCD timer:
private var timer: (any DispatchSourceTimer)?

func performRequest<T: Decodable>(
    request: T,
    onSuccess: @escaping (T) -> Void,
    onFailure: @escaping (any Error) -> Void,
    onOffline: (() -> Void)? = nil
) {
    …

    let timer = DispatchSource.makeTimerSource(queue: .main)
    self.timer = timer

    timer.schedule(deadline: .now() + 1, repeating: 1)

    timer.setEventHandler {
        if someCondition {
            onSuccess(someResult)
        } else {
            onFailure(someError)
        }
    }

    timer.activate()
}

And to cancel the timer, set timer to nil or call timer?.cancel().
In terms of embracing Swift 6, this is a step backwards. But, it does avoid the compiler warning/error (currently, at least; I suspect when they audit this for Swift concurrency, this will likely produce errors similar to what you are seeing with Timer.scheduledTimer).
